# Rails 5 - Geocoder Gem, Search with Multiple Parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm currently using this [geocoder gem](https://github.com/alexreisner/geocoder) for rails.

Currently, on my website, users input their (6 digit)Postal Code, after which, I would generate their street name by searching it on geocoder like this:

```
results = Geocoder.search(their_postal_code)
# handle results to get the street name
```

This works perfectly fine for *most* postal codes. However, for certain postal codes, it doesn't return the desired country (Singapore in this instance).

The [geocoder website](http://www.rubygeocoder.com/) does not specify a way in which you can do `Geocoder.search` with multiple params.

On the [github website](https://github.com/alexreisner/geocoder), the only one which I've come across is this:

```
# with Google:
Geocoder.search("Paris", :bounds => [[32.1,-95.9], [33.9,-94.3]])
```

Which led me to try variations such as this:

```
Geocoder.search("123456", country: "SG")
Geocoder.search("123456", country: "Singapore")
Geocoder.search("SG", postal_code: "123456")
Geocoder.search("Singapore", postal_code: "123456")
```

None of which seems to work. How would i go about searching a postal code and specifying the Country?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found what I think should be the correct answer to my problem. I have no way of replicating it yet (with a different address) since it is impossible for me to find out a "wrong" address and test it out. Anyway, here is the solution:

According to [Google's documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro#Geocoding) for Geocoding, there are a number of methods that you can Geocode a location. One of them is by `Component Filtering`, which is the one that we should be looking at.

Now I cannot say with absolute certainty if this is the correct solution, because once again, I am unable to test with any different answers. But this is what worked:

`Geocoder.search(" input your component:value pairs and separate with a | ")`

So it will look something like:

`Geocoder.search("postal_code: 123456 | country: Singapore")`

Kindly note, as per Google's documentation, the pipe `|` is a `AND` function and not a `OR` function. Hope this solves someone else's problem!